# How can I add a border/padding around a wx.StaticBox?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wx.StaticBox inside a wx.Panel. The staticbox is taking up virtually all of the space in the panel with no border. How can I add a border around the staticbox?

Some example code:

```
  self.aPanel = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, style = wx.RAISED_BORDER )

  self.aLabel = wx.StaticText( self.aPanel, -1, 'Bar' )

  self.aSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
  self.aSizer.Add( self.aLabel, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL )

  self.aBox = wx.StaticBox( self.aPanel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Foo' )
  self.aBoxSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer( self.aBox, wx.VERTICAL )
  self.aBoxSizer.Add( self.aSizer, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL )

  self.aPanel.SetSizer( self.aBoxSizer )
```

Comment: Do you mean margin around StaticBox? If so, something like self.aBoxSizer.Add( self.aSizer, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 5 ) will give you 5 px margin around it. Official doc says: Add(self, item, proportion=0, flag=0, border=0, userData=None) so border seems the correct term.

Comment: Reading the documentation led me to believe (and try) that as well but doing this adds border space _inside_ the staticbox. I want to add border space _around_ (or perhaps I should say _outside_) the staticbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess probably that's because you are using wx.StaticBoxSizer. If I replace it with wx.BoxSizer, the border parameter works as expected. Here's a minimal example. I don't know the exact layout that you want. So, it may not do what you actually want but I hope it helps as a starting point.

(edit: code modified according to comment)

```
import wx

class myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title='Test', size=(200,200))

        self.aPanel = wx.Panel(self, style = wx.RAISED_BORDER )
        self.aLabel = wx.StaticText( self.aPanel, -1, 'Bar' )
        self.aBox = wx.StaticBox(self.aPanel, -1, 'Foo')
        
        self.aSizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
        self.aSizer.Add( self.aLabel, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL )
        
        self.aBoxSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer( self.aBox, wx.VERTICAL )
        self.aBoxSizer.Add( self.aSizer, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL )
        
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.aBoxSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
        self.aPanel.SetSizer( vbox )

        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    frame = myframe()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This solution places the Bar statictext outside of the Foo staticbox. I have seen/used this form before but I need the staticbox to enclose the statictext as it does in the example I gave.

Comment: I totally missed the point that "Bar" should go inside "Foo". So, I modified the code. hope this is what you wanted.